# if employer is willing to settle prior to litigation in federal court

Tags: united-states, new-york-state

I would like to ask this question related to employer wrongful termination of the employee as a result of retaliation for employee protected activity at work. Would you give up OSHA claims if employer is willing to settle the case prior to bringing litigation in fed court ? Is it explicitly implied that you would not bring OSHA claims if employer settles the matter with you?

Answer (score 3):

A settlement can include whatever terms the parties agree on, short of terms prohibited by law. Usually one party gives up at lest some claims. Then other party nay also give up,claims, or make a payment, or both. There may be other terms as well, including confidentiality of the details. It is not uncommon for both parties to give up all claims against each other.

Settlement agreements are legally binding on both parties.

We cannot advise on what kind of settlement a particular person should take in a particular case. For tht, consult a lawyer.

Comment: The most common settlement term is to give up any and all claims that the parties have or could have against each other, even if they are unknown at the time.